# What is sum of $\sum_{x=1}^n x \log (x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

What would be the closed form of $$\sum_{x=1}^n x \log (x)$$?

I know the summation of $\sum \log x$, but how do I use this series to the $$\sum_{x=1}^n x \log (x)$$?$

Comment: But, what do you mean with "sum"? Where is te sum defined?

Comment: Summation by parts helps anyway.

Comment: Updated the limits of x!

Comment: You say you know the summation of $\sum \log x$...  Care to share with us what that is equal to?

Comment: The closed form that you mean is
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n \log(x)  = \log(n!)
$$
?

Comment: @5xum: It is the same as Jorge has pointed out.$\sum_{x=1}^n\log (x) = \log (n!)$

Comment: $\sum _{x=1}^n x \log (x)=\log (H(n))$ where $H(n)$ is: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html

Comment: @Mariusz Oh duh!  I should be known that one lol

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Please add that as an answer, to increase familiarity with the hyperfactorial (I was not aware of it).

Comment: @Deepak You may also find it [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperfactorial), where I should've noticed it...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks, another site that is new to me. But I wonder why (with regard to the accurate approximation) they said "double $7$th root" instead of just "$49$th root"?

Comment: @Deepak Because people who do googology are weird lol (coming from many of them, but I never said this)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First solution:

Note: This approach can be made more rigorous by using

$$\sum_{n=1}^xa_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-a_{n+x}$$

Whenever $a_n\to0$.  Rewrite the summand using summation by parts and polynomial terms to get it in this form.

Now we can differentiate our sums.

---

Let us define

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^xn\ln(n)$$

Then, we have

$$f(x)=x\ln(x)+f(x-1)$$

Differentiate both sides to get

$$f'(x)=\ln(x)+1+f'(x-1)$$

Solving this, we find that

$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=f'(0)+\sum_{n=1}^x\ln(n)+1\\&=f'(0)+\ln(x!)+x\\&=f'(0)+\ln(\Gamma(x+1))+x\end{align}$$

Integrate back, you'll find that

$$f(x)=f'(0)x+\psi^{(-2)}(x+1)+\psi^{(-2)}(1)+\frac12x^2\\=f'(0)x+\psi^{(-2)}(x+1)+\frac12\ln(2\pi)+\frac12x^2$$

where $\psi^{(n)}(x)$ is the [extended polygamma function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polygamma(-2,%20x)).  Plug in $x=1$ and $f(1)=0$ to get

$$\begin{align}f'(0)&=-\psi^{(-2)}(2)-\frac12\\&=\frac12-\ln(2\pi)\end{align}$$

And thus, the closed form is given by

> $$f(x)=\left(\frac12-\ln(2\pi)\right)x+\psi^{(-2)}(x+1)+\frac12\ln(2\pi)+\frac12x^2$$

---

Special values may be obtained by noting that:

$$I=\int_0^1\ln(\Gamma(t))~\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\ln(\Gamma(1-t))~\mathrm dt$$

Add them together and divide by two:

$$I=\frac12\ln(\pi)-\frac12\int_0^1\ln(\sin(\pi t))~\mathrm dt$$

And from there use the recursive formula:

$$\int_0^{n+1}\ln(\Gamma(t))~\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\ln(\Gamma(t))~\mathrm dt+\int_0^n\ln(t)+\ln(\Gamma(t))~\mathrm dt$$

---

This is related to the [Barnes G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function#Relation_to_the_Loggamma_integral) since

$$\psi^{(-2)}(x)-\psi^{(-2)}(0)=\int_0^x\ln(\Gamma(t))~\mathrm dt=\frac{x(1-x)}2+\frac x2\ln(2\pi)+x\ln(\Gamma(x))-\ln(G(x+1))$$

---

### Second solution:

Another approach to this problem would be to note that:

$$x\ln(x)=\frac d{ds}x^s\bigg|_{s=1}$$

This gives us:

> $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^xn\ln(n)&=\frac d{ds}\sum_{n=1}^xn^s\bigg|_{s=1}\\&=\frac d{ds}\big[\zeta(-s)-\zeta(-s,x+1)\big]\bigg|_{s=1}\\&=\zeta'(-1)-\zeta^{(1,0)}(-1,x+1)\end{align}$$

where [$\zeta'(-1)=\frac1{12}-\ln(A)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) and, well, I suppose we'd work out $\zeta^{(1,0)}(-1,x+1)$ in the fashion of the first solution.

Comment: I really like this solution. You even managed to work $2\pi = \tau$ into it! :)

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_n=n$, $b_n=\log n$ and $A_n=a_1+\ldots+a_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
By summation by parts

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=1}^{N}n\log n &=& \frac{N(N+1)}{2}\log N-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left[\log(n+1)-\log n\right] \\ &=&\frac{N^2}{2}\log N+\frac{N}{2}\log N-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{n+1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left[\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]\\&=&\frac{N^2}{2}\log N-\frac{N^2}{4}+\frac{N}{2}\log N+O(N).\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum _{x=1}^n x \log (x)=\log (H(n))$$

From **mathworld.wolfram.com** where: [$H(n)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html) is the hyperfactorial

Comment: And here some asymptotics https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135787/asymptotic-formula-for-the-logarithm-of-the-hyperfactorial

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it's possible to express the summation to $n$ terms as a closed form expression involving special functions.

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^n x\log x = \sum_{x=1}^n \log x^x = \log \prod_{x=1}^n x^x = \log(1^1 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 3^3 ... \cdot n^n) = \log\left(\frac{n!}{0!}\cdot \frac{n!}{1!}\cdot \frac{n!}{2!}...\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\right) = n\log n! - \log G(n+1) = n\log \Gamma(n+1) - \log G(n+1)$

where $G(n)$ is the Barnes G function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function

Comment: Nice manipulations!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks! :)