# How much information can you transfer by choosing one number out of two?

Tags: game-theory, information-theory, coding-theory

Alice and Bob are playing a game. Alice (A) and Bob (B) agree on a protocol before the game starts.

Alice gets two uniformly random integers (without duplicates) from 1 through $n$, chooses one of the two numbers, and communicates it to Bob. Bob doesn't get to see anything other than the number that Alice chose (and he knows the maximum $n$, which is fixed for the game).

#### How many bits of information $b(n)$ can possibly be transmitted per number on average, if Alice and Bob play this game for a sufficiently long time?

$b(2) = 1$ is quite obvious, but even $b(3)$ is a difficult to reason about.

One protocol I came up with is that A always output $3$ for inputs $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}$, and output $1$ or $2$ to transfer $1$ bit of information when the input is $\{1, 2\}$. This gets an average transmission rate of $\frac{1}{3}$ bits per number. But I have no idea how to generalize this to bigger $n$ or whether it's even optimal.

Comment: Note for future; this question came from a chat discussion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39835367#39835367

Comment: In the $n=3$ case, if Alice has an $1$ to send, why not send that if she gets $\{1,3\}$? She only needs to punt to $3$ if the next bit in her message is _not_ one she has available. This lets her transmit $\frac23$ bits per round on average.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, d'oh!  You should post that as an answer; I seriously doubt any further improvements will be made on it.  (But then, I doubted the initial scheme could be improved upon...my shame....)  :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point.

Comment: Does Bob need to know _with certainty_ that he has received the right message, or is it enough that the risk of getting it wrong is vanishingly small?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think noisy transmission is interesting as well, although I'm not familiar with the formalisms (I'm sure Shannon has something to say about it though).

Comment: If we disregard noisy transimission and if I understand correctly what we want is a huffman coding for strings over $\{0,1\}$ using symbols in $a_i\in[1,n]$ (i.e.- certain sequences of these symbols corresponds to a certain sequence of 0's and 1's and none of these sequences are prefixes of the other so that you can tell them apart) so that for every string $w$ over $\{0,1\}$ the expected value of the length a sequence of pairs of distinct numbers $(a_i,b_i)\in[1,n]\times[1,n]$ to be to contain a series of huffman codes corresponding to $w$ is minimized over all $w$?

Comment: @exfret, that sounds correct.  You may be interested in the additional discussion around this question in chat; in particular [the broader generalization](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39836182#39836182).  But I believe you have the stated question correctly.

Answer (score 4):

For large $n$ we can approach an efficiency of $0.188$ bits per symbol, in the following way:

In the protocol Alice can send a bit to Bob either "reliable-but-slow" or "fast-but-unreliable".

In **reliable but slow** mode, Bob ignores all symbols other than $0$ or $1$, and Alice simply waits until she gets a pair that allows her to send the symbol she needs. This takes $n/2$ symbols on average.

In **fast but unreliable** mode, Alice sends any even number for $0$ and any odd number for $1$.  One fourth of the bits she sends will be garbled because she doesn't have a number of the right parity to send.

Alice and Bob agrees in advance on a block size $b$, and the communication starts when Alice has accumulated $b$ bits to send. She sends them using fast-but-unreliable mode. Alice knows which bits went wrong, so she computes a *correction sequence* that Bob should XOR what he got with in order to get the real message. The bits in the correction sequence are not uniformly distributed: $0$ is three times as common as $1$. Therefore Alice can compress it using [arithmetic coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) to a length of about $0.811$ of the original $b$ (namely $-\frac34 \log_2(\frac34) - \frac14 \log_2(\frac14)$).

Alice uses reliable-but-slow bits to tell Bob the exact length of the compressed correction sequence, and now sends it using the same procedure as the original block -- that is, with its own correction sequence following, etc.

When the compressed corrections sequence is shorter than some prearranged length, Alice switches to sending it in reliabe-but-slow mode.

**Analysis.** When $b$ is large, the expected number of *fast-but-unreliable* symbols sent is
$$ b + 0.811b + 0.811^2b + 0.811^3b + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-0.811} b $$
There will be on the order of $\log b$ nested correction sequences, each needing up to $\log b$ reliable-but-slow bits to encode their lengths. So all in all in the reliable-but-slow phases use about $\frac n2 (\log^2 b+C)$ symbols, where $C$ accounts for the final reliable-but-slow corrections sequence).

For each particular $n$, by choosing $b$ large enough, Alice and Bob can make the $\frac n2 (\log^2 b+C)$ as small compared to $\frac{1}{1-0.811} b$ as they want! So in the limit of large $b$ they ought to achieve $1-0.811 = 0.189$ bits per symbol.

---

If $n\le 10$, the reliable mode is actually faster than the asymptotic behavior here, and should be used instead.

---

I suspect this might be asymptotically optimal for large $n$. I tried variants, such as decreasing the error percentage of the "fast" mode at the expense of speed by assigning a fraction of the $n$ symbols as "ignore this symbol" markers instead of letting all of them encode actual bits. But it looks like that always results in worse overall performance.

Comment: My mutual information computation gives 0.2786

Comment: I'm upvoting this for the clever protocol, but I am not convinced the actual numerical calculation is correct.

Comment: I think this can be further improved.  For example, it can be agreed that the symbols $0$ and $1$ shall *never* be used to encode a wrong bit.  This is possible because the other wrong symbol can always be used.  So for example, if the next bit is a $1$ but Alice only has $0$ and $2$, she can send $2$.  And then Bob can be *certain* of ALL $0$ and $1$ symbols, regardless of block size.  Something more can surely be done with this info.

Comment: What about using the "slow but reliable" channel opportunistically to communicate the correction code for the "fast but unreliable" channel?  I see problems with that, but it's worth exploring.  One other idea would be to have a reserved "stop message" symbol, after which only correction codes would be transmitted.  But it's very mind bending to reason about, so these might both be bad ideas.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard: I won't rule out that such tweaks could be an advantage; I just haven't yet found any that (a) I can analyze the effect of, and (b) turn out to improve efficiency for large $n$.

Comment: A simple use would be, use such symbols with certainty, and then disregard them when computing the error codes.  So if Alice sent a block of 32 symbols in fast-but-unreliable, but 5 of them were able to be encoded with the symbols 1 and 0, just send 5 more symbols.

Comment: And I feel there must be something wrong with your calculation in that it doesn't depend on $n$ but only on $b$.  I see you mention choosing $b$ high enough to make it not matter, but that rather assumes infinite message length.  What about instead writing the calculation as an expression involving $b$ and $n$, where for any large $n$ the limit of the expression's value as $b$ approaches infinity tends toward the numerical value you state?

Comment: @Wildcard: There is no dependency on $n$, because I'm considering the limit where $n$ is large. Whenever $n$ is finite, the requirement that two _different_ options are available to Alice means that the error rate in "fast" mode will be somewhat _better_ than $\frac14$ -- for $n=2$ the error rate is $0$; for $n=4$ it is $\frac16$; for $n=6$ it is $\frac 15$ ...

Answer (score 3):

**If Alice were not able to see the numbers before sending the max or min**, the best possible rate would be:

> $$C=\fbox{$1-\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}H\left(\frac{n-k}{n-1}\right)$}$$

Alice in the OP's problem has *strictly more* capabilities than Alice as I have written her, so the rate "OP's Alice" can achieve is *higher* than the above formula.

For large $n$ the sum becomes like an integral: $$1 - \frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{y=2}^{n-1} H\left(\frac{n-y}{n-1}\right)
 \approx 1-\int_0^1 H(p) dp = 1-1/\log(4)\approx 0.2787.$$

---

Your 'choose two numbers' specifies a channel state:

$$Z=(z_1,z_2)\sim \operatorname{Uniform}\{(a,b), 1\leq a< b\leq n\}$$

Each turn, the sender gets to input either $z_1$ or $z_2.$ So the channel input is some $X$ over an alphabet $\{\phi_i:\phi_i(Z)=z_i\},$ and the channel output is $Y=X(Z).$ Now you have a channel:

$$X\rightarrow \overset{\huge\overset{Z}{\downarrow}}{\fbox{$P_{Y|X,Z}$}}\rightarrow Y$$

and by the noisy channel coding theorem it is sufficient to compute the **channel capacity**: 
\begin{align}
C = \max_{p_X} I(X;Y) &=\max_{P_X} H(X)-H(X|Y) \\
&=\max_{p} H(p)-H(X|Y)
\end{align}
where $p=\mathbb{P}(X=\phi_1),\ H(p)=-p\log_2(p)-(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$ and $H(X|Y)=\sum_y P_Y(y)H(P_{X|Y=y}(\phi_1))$.

To be able to go further we need to start computing probabilities, which is simple if you set it up right. View your space of $Z$'s layed out as a triangle: 
\begin{matrix}
(1,2) \\
(1,3) & (2,3) \\
\vdots & & \ddots \\
(1,n) & \dots & & (n-1, n)
\end{matrix}
Now we can see:
\begin{align}
P_{Y|X=\phi_1}(y)&\textstyle =P(Z\text{ in }y^{th}\text{ column})=\mathbf{1}_{[1:n-1]}(y)\frac{n-y}{\frac{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)}{2}}=\mathbf{1}_{[1:n-1]}(y)\frac{2\cdot (n-y)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)},\\
P_{Y|X=\phi_2}(y)&\textstyle =P(Z\text{ in }(y-1)^{th}\text{ row})=\mathbf{1}_{[2:n]}(y)\frac{y-1}{\frac{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)}{2}}=\mathbf{1}_{[2:n]}(y)\frac{2\cdot (y-1)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)},\\
P_Y(y)&\textstyle = pP_{Y|X=\phi_1}(y)+(1-p)P_{Y|X=\phi_2}(y) = \left\lbrace \begin{matrix}
\frac{2         p\cdot(n-y)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)} & y=1 \\
\frac{2         p\cdot(n-y)+2\cdot(1-p)\cdot(y-1)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)} & y\in [2:n-1] \\
\frac{2\cdot(1-p)\cdot(y-1)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)} & y=n
\end{matrix}\right.\\
P_{X|Y=y}(\phi_1)&\textstyle = \left\lbrace \begin{matrix}
1 & y=1 \\
\frac{p\cdot (n-y)}{p\cdot(n-y)+(1-p)\cdot(y-1)} & y\in [2:n-1] \\
0 & y=n
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}

So in our entropy expansion we have:
\begin{align}
\max_{P_X}I(X;Y) &= \max_{p\in[0,1]} H(p) - \sum_{y=2}^{n-1}P(Y=y)H(X|Y=y) \\
&= \textstyle \max_{p\in[0,1]} H(p) - \sum_{y=2}^{n-1}\frac{2p\cdot(n-y)+2\cdot(1-p)\cdot(y-1)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)} H\left(\frac{p\cdot (n-y)}{p\cdot(n-y)+(1-p)\cdot(y-1)}\right).
\end{align}

The critical points of this function in $p$ are: 
\begin{align}
\textstyle \left\lbrace p: - \log_2\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) +
\sum_{y=2}^{n-1}\frac{2p\cdot(n-y)+2\cdot(1-p)\cdot(y-1)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)} \log_2\left(\frac{p\cdot (n-y)}{(1-p)\cdot(y-1)}\right)-
 \sum_{y=2}^{n-1}\left(\frac{2\cdot (n-2y+1)}{(n-1)\cdot (n-2)}\right)H\left(\frac{p\cdot (n-y)}{p\cdot(n-y)+(1-p)\cdot(y-1)}\right) = 0 \right\rbrace.
\end{align}

It is easy to check that $p^\ast=0.5$ is a critical point. (Indeed, in this case the first sum telescopes and cancels the first log, and the second sum becomes symmetric and cancels to 0 since $H(p)=H(1-p)$).

It is also the *only* critical point: the second derivative can be bounded below 0 (simple computation but tedious to write out, recall $H''(p)=1/(p^2-p)$ and $1-1/x \leq \log(x)\leq x-1$), thus the function is concave with its max at its critical point $p^\ast = 0.5.$

So the maximum possible rate of reliable information transmission boils down to:

\begin{align}
C&= 1 - \sum_{y=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2} H\left(\frac{n-y}{n-1}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: So, um ... what should Alice and Bob actually do in order to communicate?

Comment: In case you are unfamiliar with the classical method: they decide on a blocklength $n$, rate $R<C$, and generate $2^{nR}$ random sequences of $n$ 1s and 2s chosen according to the optimal distribution on $X$. Each sequence generated corresponds to a message. To send message $m\in [1:2^{nR}]$ they play the game $n$ times and Alice reveals to Bob the first or second number as dictated by the sequence for message $m$. Bob then computes the most likely codeword given the sequence of numbers revealed. For $n$ large enough, the p. Bob chose the wrong $m$ can be made smaller than any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: This strategy is guaranteed to work, but its impractical to actually implement. Coming up with a better strategy is precisely equivalent to figuring out how to reliably tell the difference between the output distributions $P_{Y|X=\phi_1}$ vs $P_{Y|X=\phi_2}$ using as few samples as possible. Solving this sort of problem usually takes... artistry. Even for channels we care about, the list of capacity-approaching strategies that could be called 'practical' is short: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Capacity-approaching_codes

Comment: What does "according to the optimal distribution on $X$" mean? What does the notation $[1:2^{nR}]$ mean? How does Bob "compute the most likely codeword given the sequence of numbers revealed"?

Comment: Your formula for $n = 3$ gives $1 - \dfrac{1}{3-2}H\left(\dfrac{3-2}{3-1}\right) = 1 - H\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = 0$. But we've already seen a scheme that can transfer $\dfrac{2}{3}$ bits per number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm "According to the optimal distribution on $X$" = "According to the distribution on the input $X$ which maximizes $I(X;Y)$". $[1:2^{nR}]=\{1,2,\dots,\lfloor 2^{nR}\rfloor\}$. Bob knows the collection of generated sequences, the numbers that were received, and the distribution of $Z$ so he tries all the generated sequences:
\begin{align}\phantom{=}&\max_{m}P\left(\text{These numbers were observed}|\text{Alice sent sequence #}m\right)\end{align}
Elem. of Information Theory by Cover and Network Information Theory by ElGamal provide most of the culture for this language.

Comment: @orlp, I've just realized in my problem setup I computed the capacity when Alice cannot see the numbers before she sends the max or min. Alice gains knowledge of the channel state $Z$ before sending, so the capacity should be higher than my formula. In particular I should have computed:
$$\max_{P_T}I(T;Y)$$
where $T$ is distributed over mappings from channel states $Z$ to inputs $X$: $$T\in \left\{{\scriptsize t}|{\scriptsize t:\{(a,b):1\leq a < b\leq n\}\to \{\phi_1,\phi_2\}}\right\}$$
as stated in (2) here: http://web.mit.edu/6.441/spring05/reading/IT-V45-N6.pdf

Comment: As it is I have wasted too much time on this problem already. Good luck

Comment: @enthdegree, if I'm reading these comments right, you've basically just said, "oops, I know my answer is wrong but I'm going to leave it the way it is."  If you ever revisit this I'd be interested what you come up with, but as it stands...I think I shall downvote....  Thanks for trying, anyway.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard In my defense, my lower bound on the capacity is correct, nontrivial and still applicable to this problem (I invite you to check!). Further, *in the limiting case* the lower bound is tighter than anything posted so far. Downvotes are never a thing smile about. :(

Comment: I'm sorry you feel you've wasted time, but I would happily reverse my downvote if you were at least to edit your answer to insert "Edit: this part is wrong because ____" at the appropriate point(s).  In other words, add errata even if you don't have time to fix it fully.  I *am* glad you worked on this problem.  Also, I'm afraid I don't see a lower bound described anywhere in your answer...just an upper bound, which @orlp pointed out fails when $n=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.

A quick  bound comes from considering, for $n$ even, that half of the values represent a binary $X=0$ input, the other half $X=1$.
This gives a BSC channel with crossover error probability given by the event that the two numbers I must choose from are on the "wrong" half

$$ p_e = \frac{\binom{n/2}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}}=\frac14 \frac{n-\frac12}{n-1}\approx \frac14$$

This gives a capacity of $C=1-h(p)=0.18872 \text{ bits}$, which agrees with Henning Makholm's answer.

Some caveats

- We are wasting bits (when both numbers are "good", the freedom of choosing one of the two is not used). Hence the capacity should be larger.
- This result (and this encoding schema) is in the context of the classsic Shannon capacity, where information is sent with vanishingly small probability of error - but not necessarily with zero probability of error.

---

A better, probably optimal (and even simpler) schema:

Let our "channel" simply pick the maximum of the pair when $X_n=1$, the minimum otherwise. This is channel with two inputs and $n$ outputs. The transition matrix is given by the probability of the extrema:

$$P(Y = y \mid X = 1) = \frac{2 (y-1)}{n (n-1)} =g(y;n)$$

while for $P(Y = y \mid X = 0)$ we have the symmetric distribution.

Then the capacity of this (weakly symmetric) channel is

$$C=\log(n) - H(g(y;n))$$

where $H(g(y;n))=h_T(n-1)$ is the entropy of a triangular distribution with $n-1$ positive values. Calling $s=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}$

$$h_T(n-1)= -s \left( \log s \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k +  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \log k\right)\\
=- \log s +  s \log({\mathcal H}(n-1))$$

where ${\mathcal H}$ is the [hyperfactorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135787/asymptotic-formula-for-the-logarithm-of-the-hyperfactorial).

The capacity decreases asymptotically (and very slowly) to $C_{\infty}=1-\frac{\log e}{2}\approx 0.2786$ bits (this agrees with enthdegree's value).

[image]

BTW: The $n=3$ case is, in this scheme, esentially a [binary erasure channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_erasure_channel), with $p_e=1/3$ and $C=2/3$ bits. A zero-error code with this rate (but unbounded length) can be built (rather trivially) if (and only if) we have feedback. But in this case the "feedback" is inside this virtual channel, so it would be feasible (as noted by Henning Makholm).

Answer (score -1):

Alice divides the integers 1 through n into two distinct subsets T and F (for example T = numbers <= n and F = numbers > n, or T = even numbers and F = odd numbers). If n is even then there are n/2 numbers in each subset, if n is odd then she has two sets with n/2 numbers plus an extra number (which can be considered to be the sole element of a third set O).

To transmit TRUE she sends a number from set T if possible, otherwise  from O if possible, otherwise from F if both her numbers are in that set. To transmit FALSE she does the opposite.

Bob assumes any T number is TRUE, and F number is false, and any O number carries no information.

For n = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7... the number of transmitted bits is 1, 2/3, 2/3, 3/5, 3/5, 4/7, 4/7... . I think the pattern is obvious. For sufficiently large n, the limit is 1/2 bits per transmission.

Comment: This will give an error in every fourth bit sent, on average. How will Bob knows where the errors are?

Comment: @Penguino This is just a specific solution for error rate of $\frac{1}{4}$. In fact, I think it would be more precise to state that the limit on the number of transmitted bits goes to $\frac{3}{4}$ since every bit Bob gets (at least in the limit as n goes to infinity and O becomes increasingly relatively small) is assumed to have information, and only $\frac{1}{4}$ of those have errors.

Comment: This is the approach that works perfectly for $n=3$, but to work for larger numbers you must put all additional possibilities in set O—no other way to be certain in a naive bit by bit protocol.  As @HenningMakholm said.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how you are computing your sequence.  It looks like you're showing the size of set $T$ over the value of $n$.  But that's not the same as how many bits of information are sent.

Answer (score -1):

This is a partial solution based on the following assumptions:

1. Alice wants to stream a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of bits in $\{0,1\}$. The probability that the first $k$ symbols of this sequence will be a given $w\in\{0,1\}^k$ is uniformly distributed.
2. "Bit transfer" is defined as the **unambiguous** transfer of one symbol in the word $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ which Alice wishes to send.
3. Bob receives bits in order. Thus, the only way to code bits is through prefix codes (i.e.- Alice and Bob agree beforehand that each element of some set $S$ of words, none of which is a prefix of another, corresponds to a unique word $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ and Alice sends her sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of bits by choosing numbers $c_i\in[1,n]$ so that the corresponding string is a code for a prefix of her message $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$).
4. For simplicity's sake, let's assume the set $S$ of prefix codes is finite.

With the above assumptions, we can define numerically for a given set $S\in\{1,...,n\}^*$ with the prefix property (which says no string is a prefix of another) and function $f:S\to\{0,1\}^*$ the *average bit wait time* of $(S,f)$, which we denote $\beta(S,f)$, to be equal to:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{w\in\{0,1\}^k}{E(w)}$$

where $E(w)$ is the expected value of the number of symbols in $\{1,...,n\}$ that will have to be sent before Bob can be sure that $w$ is a prefix of $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. We can then see that we are looking for $(S,f)$ such that $\beta(S,f)$ is minimized. In other words, we want to find:

$$b(n)=\sup_{(S,f)}{\frac{1}{\beta(S,f)}}$$

If you are confused about the fact that we took the inverse of $\beta$, recall that $\beta$ was defined to give the average time to **wait** for a bit, which is the inverse of the actual bit transfer wait. Obviously, this is a nontrivial problem. In fact, there may not even be an optimal solution, since there are infinitely many possible $S$, not to mention the even larger possible number of functions $f$. Thus, it could be possible that given a strategy $(S,f)$ we can always find a better one $(S',f')$.

To remedy these problems, one can put a restriction on the type of $(S,f)$ which are allowed. We could let $l_i$ be the maximum length of a word in $S$ and $l_o$ the maximum length of a word in $f(S)$, and then ask the question for the optimal strategies for each $l_i$ and $l_o$. As I said this is a partial answer, I will give the solution for $l_i=1$.

First, note that this implies that it is optimal for us to allow $S=\{1,...,n\}$. Now, given two distinct $u,v\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $f(u),f(v)≠\epsilon$, then as it is possible to get $(u,v)$ as a pair it must be the case that no matter the word $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ that Alice wants to send one of the strings $f(u)$ or $f(v)$ must map to a prefix of Alice's word. This implies that we must have $\{f(u),f(v)\}=\{0,1\}$.

As a corollary, exactly two letters in $[1,n]$ are "information carriers" in that they correspond to a zero and a one, and all the others correspond to the empty word and thus carry no information. Since on a given bit there is a $\frac{3n-2}{n^2}$ chance of getting the symbol corresponding to the bit we are looking for, $b(n)=\frac{3n-2}{n^2}$. In particular, since there is a $1-\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{m}{n-k}}{n^k}$ chance of scoring a symbol corresponding to a particular bit if we have m different symbols to choose from, the value of the generalized $b$ function with the restriction $l_o=1$ is:

$$b(n,m)=1-\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{m}{n-k}}{n^k}$$

P.S. I am going to try to generalize the method I used above to show this without the $l_o=1$ restriction, since it doesn't exactly seem necessary to me for this proof and so if I succeed I'll add an edit to this post showing the real value of $b(n,m)$.

Comment: I don't agree with your 3rd assumption unless I misunderstand it. We're not analyzing a specific message being sent, just the total bandwidth of a channel in the limit. I don't know why the information sent would need to be prefix-free. Regardless of that, I don't follow your answer. Your formula for $n = 3$ would give a bitrate of $\dfrac{7}{9}$ bits per number, which is better than the $\dfrac{2}{3}$ we saw before. Could you perhaps add an explicit protocol for $n = 3$ to your answer as an example? P.S.: the downvote is not mine.

Comment: @orlp Everything I said was correct. My formalization exactly captures the "bandwith in the limit" idea you had. That is why Alice is streaming along a sequence of bits not just a single word. Of course, we have to consider all possible sequences since we don't know what she might want to send beforehand. And I never said the message sent would have to be prefix free, just that the only way to encode it would be with prefix codes. I don't really have the time to address the rest of your concerns but it seems that this question already has an answer anyways so perhaps that's irrelevant.

Comment: Also, I know my answer was not perfect, but it is sad to see how picky SE has become. Sadly, this is why I have not spent more time on here.

Comment: @exfret, I too would be interested to see an explicit protocol giving $7/9$ bits per number for $n=3$.  I think it would very nicely round out this answer.  :)